# how to get the type of uicontrol event?

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3

AS 3.0 code

```
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, eventHandler);
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, eventHandler);
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, eventHandler);

function eventHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(e.type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN)
    {
        //do stuff about mouseDownEvent
    }
    else if(e.type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP)
    {
        //do stuff about mouseUpEvent
    }
    else if(e.type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER)
    {
        //do stuff about mouseOverEvent
    }
}
```

cocoa Code

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEvent:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEvent:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEvent:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];


- (void)buttonEvent:(UIButton *)sender withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
       // how to get a UIControlEvents Type?
}
```

I want getting the type of UIControl Event... i searching a cocoa documents, but failed.

plz help me ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a different method for each event.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean [Control State](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) ?

Note:Find **"Control State"** Topic